# Fastlane - fastlane init causes No such file or directory exception

Tags: android, ruby, fastlane

I'm trying to add fastlane to my android app. However when I try to run `fastlane init` I'm reciving an error :

```
C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx>fastlane init
[✔] 

[17:49:09]: Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling
[17:49:09]: Check out https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more details

Traceback (most recent call last):
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:42:in `start'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:353:in `run'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:115:in `run!'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/analytics/analytics_session.rb:22:in `action_launched'     
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/analytics/analytics_session.rb:59:in `should_show_message?'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.198.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/module.rb:28:in `fastlane_user_dir'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block in mkdir_p'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `reverse_each'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_mkdir - Z:/.fastlane (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I'm using Ruby 2.7.0p0 cause I know there are issues with other versions. Any ideas what can be wrong ?

Comment: Were you able to get this solved?